# SignalR - .Net Core 3 HubContext

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to do this. But HubContext is not available. This is in .Net Core 3 version.

```
 services.AddScoped<IHubContext<Inventory>, HubContext<Inventory>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the `IHubContext` to it be available to you. You just need to add the class you need as Transient or Scoped. Then you just inject via DI the context to you class.

```cs
private Inventory Inventory
{
    get
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Inventory>();
    }
}
```